# Want to extract uppercase and lower case letters from a list of words

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract uppercase a lowercase letters and numbers from a dictionary and print its format using python

Ex., Input Dictionary= {'Name': ['AgbAA21', 'sdsd21S'], 'address': ['AGDB323andnd', 'sbfsj@2342'], 'phone': ['909898986', '23423*(*#']}

Expected Output = {'Name': ['AaaAA99', 'aaaa99A'], 'address': 'AAAA999aaaaa', 'aaaaa@9999'], 'phone': '999999999', '99999*(*#']}

```
for key,value in outputDict.items(): 

    for wiki in value:
        fmt = ''
        for c in wiki:
            if c.islower():
                fmt += 'a'
            elif c.isupper():
                fmt += 'A'
            elif c.isdigit():
                fmt += '9'
            else:
                fmt+=c
        output.append(fmt)
    print(key,output)

Expected result :{'Name': ['AaaAA99', 'aaaa99A'], 'address': 'AAAA999aaaaa', 'aaaaa@9999'], 'phone': '999999999', '99999*(*#']}


Actual result:

Name ['AaaAA99', 'aaaa99A']
address ['AaaAA99', 'aaaa99A', 'AAAA999aaaaa', 'aaaaa@9999']
phone ['AaaAA99', 'aaaa99A', 'AAAA999aaaaa', 'aaaaa@9999', '999999999', '99999*(*#']
```

Comment: Is your example Input list correct (or vice versa ) given the expected output list ?  Please confirm - thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use regex for this, just iterate through all the characters in the string.

Then we check if the character is uppercase using `isupper()`, lowercase using `islower()` or a digit using `isdigit()`, and for any other case, we append the character directly, and we create our output string accordingly, finally we append it to the output list

```
inputDict =  {'Name': ['AgbAA21', 'sdsd21S'], 'address': ['AGDB323andnd', 'sbfsj@2342'], 'phone': ['909898986', '23423*(*#']}
outputDict = {}

for key,value in inputDict.items():

    output = []
    for wiki in value:
        fmt = ''
        for c in wiki:
            if c.islower():
                fmt += 'a'
            elif c.isupper():
                fmt += 'A'
            elif c.isdigit():
                fmt += '9'
            else:
                fmt+=c
        output.append(fmt)
    outputDict[key] = output

print(outputDict)
```

The output will look like

```
{'Name': ['AaaAA99', 'aaaa99A'], 
'address': ['AAAA999aaaaa', 'aaaaa@9999'], 
'phone': ['999999999', '99999*(*#']}
```